# PHP - can't display full set of results, just the first

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with one form I am building. I want to show a drop down of events which fulfil two conditions:

1. they are in one of the "active" competitions for each user
2. they took place today or yesterday.

Unfortunately, I only manage to show the first instance of the list, as opposed to all of them. I know for certain that the system "sees" the others as if I order the results DESC, it'll show me the last one.

The first query, for `$compcheck`, checks all the competitions that are active for a certain user. Competitions range from 1 to 5, and any user can be active in as many as he likes.

The problem occurs when trying to define the `<options>` in the drop down. I thought that by putting it into the while, it'd do that for each of the results found in `$compcheck` but it won't do it.

It's not that easy to explain either! This is at least my fourth re-write of the code (if anything, it streamlined it a lot).

```
$compcheck = mysql_query("SELECT competition FROM RCO_contracts WHERE partB='$UserID' AND state='A'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($compcheck);

if($numrows = 0)
{
     echo "You are not participating in any competition at the moment.";
}
else
{

    $yesterday = $day-1;

    echo "<form action='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Appeals_Add.php?op=add_appeal&id=$UserID' method='post'>";
    MODW_Buttons_Select(Normal,UAdminSelUser,RCO_users,completename,id,completename,False,False,$UserID,$do,$RKP);
    echo "<select name='event'>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($compcheck))
    {
        $comp = "$row[0]";

        $complabel = mysql_query("SELECT competition FROM DCO_competitions WHERE id='$comp'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($complabel))
        {
            $compname = "$row[0]";
        }

        $calendarlist = mysql_query("SELECT id, event, category FROM DCO_calendar WHERE category='$comp' AND (day='$day' OR day='$yesterday') AND month=$month AND year=$year");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($calendarlist))
        {
            $event_id = "$row[0]";
            $event_name = "$row[1]";

            echo "<option value='$event_id'>$compname $event_name</option>";
        }   

        echo "</select>";

    }
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //lap
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //timestamp
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //textarea
    MODW_Buttons_Button(Normal,Normal,Normal,Normal,None,$RKP,$id,BGenSu,$intern,$intcont);
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Comment: Please don't mind the buttons at the very end - they're stuff I still have to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were also closing `</select>` after each occurrence of the user (it's worth checking source code of the page php script has produced) - your query weren't for each occurrence of competition. try this:

```
if($numrows == 0)
{
     echo "You are not participating in any competition at the moment.";
}
else
{

    $yesterday = $day-1;

    echo "<form action='$RKP/kernel/lib/php_lib/action/AC_Appeals_Add.php?op=add_appeal&id=$UserID' method='post'>";
    MODW_Buttons_Select(Normal,UAdminSelUser,RCO_users,completename,id,completename,False,False,$UserID,$do,$RKP);
    echo "<select name='event'>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($compcheck))
    {
        $comp = "$row[0]";

        $complabel = mysql_query("SELECT competition FROM DCO_competitions WHERE id='$comp'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($complabel))
        {
            $compname = "$row[0]";

            $calendarlist = mysql_query("SELECT id, event, category FROM DCO_calendar WHERE category='$comp' AND (day='$day' OR day='$yesterday') AND month=$month AND year=$year");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($calendarlist))
            {
                $event_id = "$row[0]";
                $event_name = "$row[1]";

                echo "<option value='$event_id'>$compname $event_name</option>";
            }   

    }

    echo "</select>";
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //lap
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //timestamp
    MODW_Buttons_Input(Normal,Normal,UPerRegTeamWeb,$lang,$link,False,$UserID); //textarea
    MODW_Buttons_Button(Normal,Normal,Normal,Normal,None,$RKP,$id,BGenSu,$intern,$intcont);
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. Was it caused by the Select closing tag being within the occurrence?

Comment: select tag would mess you page, but you should've still see other options. It is moving third while inside second while should've solve it (as you want `while's` to run on each row fetched to php.

Answer (score 4):

```
if($numrows = 0)
```

You have a missing equals-sign here.

Additionally you should not put variables into a string to reassign them. Simply use `$comp = $row[0]` When you want to insert Variables into a string you should concatenate them with a dot (`"abc".$comp."def")`), it is easier to read and less error-prone.

`Normal` I don´t think you have a constant called Normal, you probably wanted a string.

Correcting these errors will help to find the problem (when it does not solve it). For developing always use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see all the errors and notices.

Edit: In HTML you should double quotes around your attributes, single quotes are a bad style.

Comment: Thanks - the "Normal" is just calling up some variables designed to show the buttons (which is not something I am dabbling into atm).